# How to optimize spacemacs, and how to highlight cursor position?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

1. I have recently installed spacemacs on my mac, and want to figure out a way to highlight the cursor position, the line I am on is always highlighted in green, but I often am unable to find the cursor on that line.
2. I also want to figure out how to optimize spacemacs. In the beginning there was an option when installing to install all packages, or a light weight mode. I want to see if I can switch to the light weight mode to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do :-

1. Get the [beacon](https://github.com/Malabarba/beacon) package. It makes it so that you can never lose your cursor position :) You also have the option to blink the cursor position if you ever lose it. Check their github page for more info

<del>2. The best way to optimise emacs is using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) for managing all the packages configuration. `use-package` helps in reducing loading time of emacs and tiding up your configuration.</del>

Comment: in `spacemacs` you can add additional packages by adding them to the `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` variable in your `.spacemacs`, then you have to restart emacs and packages should get installed automatically. I think spacemacs builds around `use-packages` and it is probably not wise to use it directly.

Comment: @gdkrmr thank you for pointing out. I did not know that about spacemacs. I only vanilla emacs.